# Componente poll não chama o método

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou querendo chamar um método periodicamente mas o `listner` do `poll` não chama o método desejado. Abaixo os meus códigos:

```
    <p:poll interval="10" update=":listaEncomendas:viewFull:resultadoPendentes,msgAtualizacao"
        listener="#{encomendaController.verificarAtualizacao()}" />
```

O controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EncomendaController implements Serializable {

public void verificarAtualizacao() throws Exception {
        final List<Encomenda> encomendas = service.findAll();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(encomendas)) {
            for (Encomenda encomenda : encomendas) {
                Encomenda encomendaAux = consultarEncomenda(encomenda.getCodigo());
                if (encomendaAux.getEventos().size() > encomenda.getEventos().size()) {
                    encomendas.remove(encomenda);
                    atualizarEncomenda(encomenda, encomendaAux);
                    encomendas.add(encomenda);
                    service.atualizar(encomenda);
                    JsfUtils.enviarEmail(encomenda);
                }
            }
        }
        pesquisar(encomendas);
    }
}
```

Uma observação é que isso começou ocorrer após incluir o listner, atualizar coisas na tela etc estava funcionando.

Comment: O `p:poll` está entre `h:form` ?

Comment: @Henrique está sim.